# Lightning Process Builder - Owner Update on Opportunity

Tags: process-builder, lightning

Our objective is to set the Owner as a generic user for all newly created opportunities of a specific record type.

I was able to implement the above via Lightning Process Builder (*is there a short form for this ? :)* )

In order for the owner to be set as the generic user (who handles opportunities) I have to actually specific the salesforce Id like shown in the image.

[image]

Is there an alternate way to achieve the owner update without actually specifying the salesforce Id ?

Comment: can you create a reference of the generic user as global constant or a user look on account object. If so all you have to do is click on the drop down in the type where it says ID and change to reference/ global constant

Comment: Thanks Rao...can you tell me how to create a Global Constant..I searched in Setup and I could not find it...or should I have to create this resource directly in process builder ?..tx

Comment: @ZenSeeker - If you change the ID using the select list to a reference does it allow you to pick a group or something that will work? I do not recall of the top of my head. I know you can set it to a reference and not an ID though.

Comment: @ZenSeeker I believe global constant cannot be created, salesforce has provided the isnull checker to either assign or check for null values. Your best bet would be to create a custom setting reference in a formula field on oppty. Meanwhile vote for this idea on accessing custom setting directly in process builder https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DfGeAAK